# Ajax loading properly only every other WP post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my wordpress site I'm loading my posts via ajax.
But for some reason every other post the page chooses to refresh instead of loading through ajax.
So when I click on Next, the next post loads in perfectly. Then in the second post when I click Next again the page refreshes.
Any ideas why it only refreshes every second post?

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.arrows a').click(function() {
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content');
        return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: The chances are, you overwriting the click elements witih your main-content override (if ```.arrows a``` is inside ```#main-content```). So, place it outside, or re-add the click handler after the load.

Comment: It is inside, it must be. How would the code look if i were to re-add the click handler after the load like you said?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var clickHandler = function() {
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content', function() {
            jQuery('.arrows a').click(clickHandler);
        });
        return false;
    };

    jQuery('.arrows a').click(clickHandler);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Delegate the click so that you aren't removing the element with the click handler.

For jQuery >= 1.7, use `on`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#main-content').on('click', '.arrows a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content');
  });
});
```

For jQuery 1.4.2-1.7, use `delegate` instead of `on`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#main-content').delegate('.arrows a', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>Loading...</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content');
  });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, doesn't load anything everything just refreshes.

Comment: @MiaGilin Are there any errors in the console? This solution assumed that the links were within `#main-content`.

Comment: @MiaGilin See the updated answer. It includes `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default link behavior instead of `return false`.

Comment: No errors, yet still refreshes every Next click. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MiaGilin There must be something else going on. This is working on my machine.

Comment: can you take a look at it? radonicrodgers. com/radonicrodgers-travel-tourism-work-wins-top-international-awards

Comment: @MiaGilin This page is still using the original javascript. Is it possibly cached?

Comment: Ok now it's using yours. Thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: @MiaGilin I see you are using jQuery 1.4.1, this does not support `on`. You will need to use a later version (>= 1.7) or see the other answer to this question. You could also use 1.4.2 and use `delegate` instead of `on`.

Comment: You are a rockstar! thanks buddy :) SHOOT any way to make the URL change though?

Comment: That's for another question (this comment chain is way too long already). You should be able to find some solutions out there. Also, remember it is best to accept an answer if your question was resolved.